Can an HTTP response contain both a file to be downloaded and a redirect location?
The accepted answer to this question Content-Disposition with 302 redirect is possibly no longer true, and suffers from over-adaptation to the original question.
The general question is: can you make a HTTP response where you both download a file while also redirecting the page.
The answer from the above-referenced question seems to imply that if you buffer your output and have a proper Content-length header (not Transfer-encoding: chunked), then Content-disposition: attachment with filename should download the response body and with the Location: header redirect to that location.
My experience is while the answer to the above referenced question says that you can have a download and redirect together if you buffer your output and send in one fell swoop, it still doesn't work. And it depends on the HTTP response status. If I respond with 200 the download works and the Location header is being ignored. If I respond with 302 or 303, then the redirect works but the download is being ignored.
And I suppose all of that is dependent on the browser, and I wonder if there is any official specification talking about this matter? Because there is no point in tweaking a solution which is working just by accident on some browsers.
And if that combination of Content-disposition and Location and status 3xx is not working, then what could be done instead? I do not want the target page of the redirect to also deal with the download. I am reading about sending multipart responses, and people talk about multipar/form-data. But why form-data? How about a multipart/mixed? Is that officially supported? You could send one part with Content-disposition: inline and Content-type: text/html and that would be displayed, and another part with Content-disposition: attachment, and that would be saved. The displayed HTML could then do a redirect with a <meta http-equiv="refresh" ...> tag.
But since it is quite tricky for me to suddenly implement MIME multipart responses, I wanted to ask this question before trying it.
Really no way to make Content-disposition: attachment and Location: with status 303 working? Is it officially not supported by the specs?
And if not, is any multipart/mixed response working on all browsers or does it have to be shoehorned into a multipart/form-data somehow?
PS: to avoid deletes as duplicate I say why similar questions do not answer this one:

Download file and redirect in a response - this is too specific for python and django and has no real answer.
Content-Disposition headers to allow both download and open file - this question began with a misunderstanding and the answer only corrected that.
Header Location + Content Disposition - this just assumes that you can't do both, but it's phrased as an opinion and suggestion rather than as a hard "can't do" and contradicts the information from the answer in the initially cited question.

I have tried to make a multipart response, using a simple CGI shell script with Apache as follows:
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="schnipp-schnapp"

--schnipp-schnapp
Content-type: text/html
Content-disposition: inline

<html>
  <head>
    <meta equiv="refresh" content="10; url=https://stackoverflow.com"/>
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Here</h1>
  </body>
</html>

--schnipp-schnapp
Content-type: text/xml
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="attachment.xml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <toot/>
</root>

--schnipp-schnapp--
EOF

And I tested this as an email where it is understood fine. But as an HTTP response the browser will simply save the entire multipart thing after the initial headers. That is, it is unable to interpret the multipart package.
I have tried multipart/form-data as well, and it showed the same behavior. Is this just something I do wrong or the browsers really don't understand multipart responses?
There are answers about this question: Browser support of multipart responses so in short, no. This is an elusive idea that no browser really supports.

Using a pure HTTP/HTML solution the answer is probably no. With Javascript all kinds of workarounds are possible, but whether that's helpful depends on why you need this in the first place I think.
